# SQL Server stored procedure . Select and update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm stuck and in need of some help please. I am using SQL Server 2017.

I have written a stored procedure which is being pulled into Crystal Reports. The report is a picking list. When it has been printed I want to update column `PickingSlip` with 'Y'

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Picking] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        SorMaster.SalesOrder, SorDetail.SalesOrderLine, SorDetail.StockCode, SorDetail.OrderQty, SorDetail.ShipQty
    FROM
        SorMaster 
    INNER JOIN 
        SorDetail ON SorMaster.SalesOrder = SorDetail.SalesOrder
    WHERE
        SorDetail.OrderQty = SorDetail.ShipQty 
        AND (PickingSlip = '')

    UPDATE SorDetail
    SET PickingSlip = 'Y'
    WHERE
        SorDetail.OrderQty = SorDetail.ShipQty 
        AND PickingSlip = ''
END
```

The report is blank. The update is working so I'm guessing the SP completes and then generates output into Crystal Reports, which is why I'm not seeing anything.

How can I update also get an output?

Comment: There should be 2 things that stick ouot as obvious to you 1) There could be an issue with your WHERE predicate of PickingSlip=''. Is there a chance these are null and not empty string? 2) Your INNER JOIN could possibly need to be a LEFT JOIN. Look at these things and come back if the issue isnt obvious. WHen you come back show us the two tables

Comment: if you can add some data and table scripts it is possible to test this. As of now  it is possible your join or where clause  does not return data.  
if it returns data it will show only once as (initial load only) as after select you update the data in the second query. 
This can happen.

Comment: The inner join is fine. On the update I missed off a filter for PickingSlip = '' . My copy and paste skills aren't on point today.

Comment: That kind of code is going to leave you open to concurrency issues. What happens to new `SortDetail` records that appear in the system between your `select` and `update` statement? Looks like they'll be marked as picked but never get output in a picking list.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Or what happens if the report fails to print.... or any manner of other issues that could happen along the way... There should be two separate operations here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal doesn't know what part of the SP it should use as the result set.
Perhaps you could load the SELECT into a temporary table, do the update, and finish by returning the temp table.

Or remove the update statement and call it from another SP used in a subreport.

Or call the update statement from a Crystal formula using a UFL.

Comment: Thanks. INSERT into TEMP , UPDATE  and DROP gave me the solution I needed.